# Moralis.Auth.verify 400 bad request error

Tags: solidity, wallets, authentication, moralis

I'm following the moralis tutorial to build an authentication and authorization system with moralis and reactJS https://docs.moralis.io/authentication-api/evm/how-to-authenticate-users-with-metamask-using-react. I get this error when i hit this route `http://localhost:4000/verify`. The code that creates this error is the following:

```
const { address, profileId } = (
      await Moralis.Auth.verify({
        message,
        signature,
        networkType: "evm",
      })
    ).raw;
```

This is the full code of the request:

```
const Moralis = require("moralis").default;

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// to use our .env variables
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// allow access to React app domain
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

const config = {
  domain: process.env.APP_DOMAIN,
  statement: "Please sign this message to confirm your identity.",
  uri: process.env.REACT_URL,
  timeout: 60,
};

app.post("/verify", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { message, signature } = req.body;

    const { address, profileId } = (
      await Moralis.Auth.verify({
        message,
        signature,
        networkType: "evm",
      })
    ).raw;

    const user = { address, profileId, signature };

    // create JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.AUTH_SECRET);

    // set JWT cookie
    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
    });

    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Full message error:

```
MoralisError [Moralis SDK Core Error]: [C0006] Request failed, Bad Request(400): Invalid message: {"success":false,"state":103,"length":277,"matched":0,"maxMatched":5,"maxTreeDepth":15,"nodeHits":184,"inputLength":277,"subBegin":0,"subEnd":277,"subLength":277}
    at RequestController.makeError (/Users/filippomeda/Desktop/dev/web3/income/Improver/server/node_modules/@moralisweb3/common-core/lib/cjs/index.cjs:1224:20)
    at RequestController.<anonymous> (/Users/filippomeda/Desktop/dev/web3/income/Improver/server/node_modules/@moralisweb3/common-core/lib/cjs/index.cjs:1205:38)
    at step (/Users/filippomeda/Desktop/dev/web3/income/Improver/server/node_modules/@moralisweb3/common-core/lib/cjs/index.cjs:83:23)
    at Object.throw (/Users/filippomeda/Desktop/dev/web3/income/Improver/server/node_modules/@moralisweb3/common-core/lib/cjs/index.cjs:64:53)
    at rejected (/Users/filippomeda/Desktop/dev/web3/income/Improver/server/node_modules/@moralisweb3/common-core/lib/cjs/index.cjs:55:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  isMoralisError: true,
  code: 'C0006',
  details: {
    status: 400,
    response: {
      status: 400,
      statusText: 'Bad Request',
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      data: [Object]
    }
  },
  [cause]: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
      at settle (/Users/filippomeda/Desktop/dev/web3/income/Improver/server/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:1909:12)
      at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/filippomeda/Desktop/dev/web3/income/Improver/server/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2989:11)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
    code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Array],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 20000,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: Infinity,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://authapi.moralis.io/challenge/verify/evm',
      params: {},
      data: '{"message":"http://localhost:3000 wants you to sign in with your Ethereum account:\\n0xa9B54220AD207Cf6fffb587493ff774c6d763706\\n\\nPlease sign this message to confirm your identity.\\n\\nURI: http://localhost:3000\\nVersion: 1\\nChain ID: 1\\nNonce: Qk1yAs9wQ9u1It47Q\\nIssued At: 2023-07-17T12:10:57.277Z","signature":"0x2a47b5edf79b27eab4638e8ac86696ab60628b43f4bf11f0323f697f8eeda384327c13cf6e94171552920f5043e062244a29e16b152bcc1dee8f91c53bd0030b1c"}'
    },
    request: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /challenge/verify/evm HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'x-moralis-platform: NodeJS SDK\r\n' +
        'x-moralis-platform-version: 2.22.4\r\n' +
        'x-moralis-build-target: node\r\n' +
        'x-api-key:notsharingapukey\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.4.0\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 447\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: authapi.moralis.io\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/challenge/verify/evm',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'authapi.moralis.io',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    response: {
      status: 400,
      statusText: 'Bad Request',
      headers: [AxiosHeaders],
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      data: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

If you have any suggestion please let me know it.

Comment: Hi, Did you get any other error logs in your code editor console? More details about the error might help to debug further. 
Since the error happened at `/verify` a possible cause for the error can be incorrect message, signature params sent from frontend code.

Comment: i added the full error message to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here occurred due to the incorrect format of APP_DOMAIN variable. The accepted format is `RFC 4501` dns authority format. So as an example, the APP_DOMAIN name should be like `stackexchange.com` for the website uri `https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/`.

Since you are on localhost the APP_DOMAIN will just `localhost`.